# Access denied when using OAuth2 on rabbitmq with Azure AD

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, rabbitmq

I am trying to use OAuth2 on rabbitmq with provider Azure AD (only for the management UI). I am using the docker image rabbitmq:3.11-management.

I have created an SPA app registration on Azure AD with a redirection url to the management UI home page. I have then created two app roles :

```
<client_id>.tag:monitoring
<client_id>.read:*/*
```

I have assigned those app roles to myself on Azure AD.

On rabbitmq side, I have put this configuration :

```
  auth_backends.1 = rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2

  auth_backends.2 = internal

  auth_oauth2.https.peer_verification = verify_none #for now

  auth_oauth2.https.peer_verification = verify_none

  auth_oauth2.resource_server_id=<app_registration_client_id>
auth_oauth2.jwks_url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/discovery/v2.0/keys

  auth_oauth2.default_key = <JWT_key> # I have tried doing this in case of issue with jwt key, I have chosen a key from list

  auth_oauth2.additional_scopes_key=roles

  management.oauth_enabled=true  

  management.oauth_client_id=<app_registration_client_id> 

  management.oauth_client_secret=<app_registration_secret> #not used as I have tried to allowPublic access on app registration


  management.oauth_provider_url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<client_id>
```

When I connect to management UI I have the 'Click Here to Login' Button as expected with the used plugin but when I click, I have Not Authorized error.

In rabbitmq logs I have this (in debug mode):

```
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0> User '043f5ce4-45da-478a-8c74-f7b799859141' authentication failed with error:undef:
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0> [{rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2,user_login_authentication,
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>      [<<"043f5ce4-45da-478a-8c74-f7b799859141">>,
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>       [{password,
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>            <<"eyJ**********8Kw">>}]],
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>      []},
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>  {rabbit_access_control,try_authenticate,3,
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>      [{file,"rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,86}]},
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>  {rabbit_access_control,'-check_user_login/2-fun-0-',4,
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>      [{file,"rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,51}]},
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>  {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1350}]},
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>  {rabbit_access_control,check_user_login,2,
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>      [{file,"rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,36}]},
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>  {rabbit_mgmt_util,is_authorized,7,[{file,"rabbit_mgmt_util.erl"},{line,280}]},
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>  {cowboy_rest,call,3,[{file,"src/cowboy_rest.erl"},{line,1575}]},
2023-06-06 06:04:20.426917+00:00 [debug] <0.15140.0>  {cowboy_rest,is_authorized,2,[{file,"src/cowboy_rest.erl"},{line,368}]}]
2023-06-06 06:04:20.427353+00:00 [warning] <0.15140.0> HTTP access denied: User '043f5ce4-45da-478a-8c74-f7b799859141' authentication failed with internal error. Enable debug logs to see the real error.
```

I have tried to see the content headers of the JWT Token and the result is that I see the claim 'roles' and I see in it the roles I have...

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the issue, it was a confusion between the plugin name and module name: `auth_backends.1 = rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2`

The right one is :   `auth_backends.1 = rabbit_auth_backend_oauth2`

Discussion: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/8512